# Listview's selected item not in sync with the selected state of an item unless my mouse pointer is released after selecting

Tags: c#, listview, uwp

I have a list view with few items. Whenever, I select my list view item, it's corresponding selected state is lagging behind until my key pad or mouse pointer is released. What should be done in order that the selection of item is immediately reflected when I just click on the item irrespective of whether the key/mouse pointer is released. I tried with the basic listview with items and it seems to be a default behavior... Just curious to know if this can be overridden

Attached below the sample image of the same where the pink color denotes an already selected item and grey color is the item that is about to be selected with my mouse/key still not released which gives an impression that it is still not yet selected and it is lagging behind. How can I make sure that the grey selection automatically turns to pink irrespective of my mouse/key release.

[image]

```
<ListView x:Name="TestingList" 
                              ItemsSource="{x:Bind TestListing.Details}"                               
                              SelectedItem="{x:Bind TestListing.DefaultSelected,Mode=TwoWay}"    
                              SelectionChanged="TestList_SelectionChanged"                              
                               SelectionMode="Single">
                        <ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
                            <TransitionCollection/>
                        </ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="test:TestingName">
                                <TextBlock Margin="42,5,0,0" Style="{StaticResource TextStyle}"  
                                           Text="{x:Bind Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: It won't be a "click" until you release the pointer.

Comment: You might have done some customizations for the ListView. Please provide a [mcve] to show what you have done.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT I didn't make any customizations to my listview.. just disabled the animation behvaior for my listview ... I've added the snippet above

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz Is it possible to override that behavior?

Comment: @Karthik You can handle MouseDown, KeyDown  and similar events in the ListView and select the item on those events. It might need quite a lot of work to make it work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out a way to handle this.

1. Add a pointer pressed event to the textblock.
2. Empty the selected item to null in the pointer pressed event. This immediately clears the selected state of item when the pointer is in pressed state and since, the selection changed event gets triggered only after this event, clearing in pressed state doesn't affect the new item selected.
3. Get the data context from the pointer pressed event and do the needed operations.

It solves my use case. Thank you @Xavier and @Mehrzad for your time on this. Much appreciated.

**XAML**

```
<ListView x:Name="TestingList" 
                              ItemsSource="{x:Bind TestListing.Details}"                               
                              SelectedItem="{x:Bind TestListing.DefaultSelected,Mode=TwoWay}"    
                              SelectionChanged="TestList_SelectionChanged"                              
                               SelectionMode="Single">
                        <ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
                            <TransitionCollection/>
                        </ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="test:TestingName">
                                <TextBlock Margin="42,5,0,0" Style="{StaticResource TextStyle}"  PointerPressed="Test_PointerPressed" 
                                           Text="{x:Bind Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

**XAML.cs**

```
private void Test_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
 {
            TestingList.SelectedItem = null;
            TestingName x = e.OriginalSource as TextBlock).DataContext as TestingName);

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Whenever, I select my list view item, it's corresponding selected state is lagging behind until my key pad or mouse pointer is released.

I finally understand your question. The behavior you described is default behavior. Please follow my steps to understand the basic principles.

**Click the 'Document Outline in visual studio' -> right click your ListView control -> Edit Additional Templates -> Edit Generated Item Container(ItemContainerStyle) -> Edit a Copy**

You will get a style of ListViewItem. Find the `ListViewItemPresenter` in ControlTemplate. You will see `PressedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundPressed}"` and `SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelected}"`. If you change the `PressedBackground` to 'ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelected', it will be that you want.

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemRevealStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
......
<Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <ListViewItemPresenter x:Name="Root"  CheckBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBrush}" ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxBrush}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" CheckMode="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckMode}" DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}" DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackground}" DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForeground}" FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusBorderBrush}" FocusVisualMargin="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualMargin}" FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusSecondaryBorderBrush}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True" 
                                           PressedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundPressed}" PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackground}" PointerOverForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemForegroundPointerOver}" PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundPointerOver}" RevealBorderThickness="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderThemeThickness}" ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" RevealBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrush}" RevealBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBackground}" SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemForegroundSelected}" SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled}" 
                                           SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelected}" SelectedPressedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPressed}" SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
```

Comment: Thank you @Xavier .. this helps.. On the same note, is there a way to clear the selected background for the previously selected item ? The reason being it gives an impression as though there are two selected items for a split sec...

Comment: @Karthik If you have not done other operations, this is default behavior. When you select a new item, the previous item will be unselected. So, I did not understand your question about ' is there a way to clear the selected background for the previously selected item ?'.

Comment: I've attached a sample image above for better understanding..."Second Project" is an already selected item and "First project" is my new selection without my key press released. Only, when my key press for "First project" is released, the selection for my "Second Project" is getting cleared. I understand that its the default behavior... but just wondering if there are any hacks to get through this..

Comment: @Karthik No. There's no way.